# Three points in $\mathbb R^5$

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

How can I find the affine subspace $\pi$ that contains the following points?

$ P:(1,0,2,0,1)\\
Q:(0,1,0,1,0)\\
R:(2,0,1,0,2)$

Surely it is easy in $\mathbb R^3$, but I don't understand how can I determinate $\pi$ and the distance between the points in $\mathbb R^5$! (I need these information because I have to determine the area of the triangles that has P Q and R as vertices)

Comment: Ps: maybe you can suggest me a good pdf 'bout affine geometry

Comment: Which kind of description of the result do you want? A parametric description could be $$ \{ P+t(Q-P)+u(R-P)\mid t,u\in\mathbb R \} $$ exactly like in three dimensions.

Comment: the exercise require cartesian and parametric description

Comment: Then just plug in the values for $P$, $Q$, $R$ in @HenningMakholm 's formula

Comment: thanks guys!!!!

Comment: How can I do cartesian description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you’re ultimately after is the area of the triangle, you can simply use *Heron’s formula* $$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)},$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the side lengths and $s$ is the semi-perimeter $\frac12(a+b+c)$. The side lengths are just the distances between the points, which you can compute using the usual formula, e.g., $$a=PQ=\sqrt{(1-0)^2+(0-1)^2+(2-0)^2+(0-1)^2+(1-0)^2} = 2\sqrt2.$$

A parametric equation for the plane isn’t really any different than it would be for points in $\mathbb R^3$. Pick one as your “base” point and compute the two vectors to the other points, e.g., $P+s(Q-P)+t(R-P)$. Alternatively, you could use three parameters: $${m_1P+m_2Q+m_3R\over m_1+m_2+m_3}.$$ (This should look familiar to you if you’re encountered barycentric coordinates.)

Since you’re working in $\mathbb R^5$, you will need three implicit Cartesian equations of the form $a_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4x_4+a_5x_5=0$. Plugging in the coordinates of the three points will generate a system of three linear equations in the coefficients $a_i$. A basis of the three-dimensional solution space will give you three independent equations. In other words, compute a basis for the null space of the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&2&0&1\\1&0&1&0&1&0\\1&2&0&1&0&2\end{bmatrix}.$$ This, too, is no different from the way one might go about doing this in $\mathbb R^3$, but in that case the null space will only be one-dimensional.

Comment: How ca I find the direction of this affine space?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaFuente What do you mean by “direction?” Unlike the situation in $\mathbb R^3$, which is special in many ways, the orthogonal complement of a plane in $\mathbb R^5$ is three-dimensional, so there’s no single “normal vector” to the plane.

Comment: I can write the affine subspace in this form: $S=P+W=\{P+w\;| w\in W\}$ right? We called W "the direction" of the subaffine space.
I think the direction could be the point that we called $P$ in our problem, what do you think?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaFuente No, it’s the span of $Q-P$ and $R-P$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what form you hope for for a presentation of $\pi$, but let me address the part your question about how to determine the area of the triangle with those vertices.

You can find the area of a triangle knowing an angle along with the lengths of the two incident sides.  In particular, you need only the sine of that angle.  Consider angle $\angle PQR$.  The length of $PQ$ is $\sqrt{(1-0)^2+(0-1)^2+(2-0)^2+(0-1)^2+(1-0)^2}=2\sqrt{2}$, and the length of $QR$ is $\sqrt{(0-2)^2+(1-0)^2+(0-1)^2+(1-0)^2+(0-2)^2}=\sqrt{11}$.  We can get the cosine using dot products $$(P-Q)\cdot (R-Q)=\lVert PQ\rVert \lVert QR\rVert\cos(\angle PQR),$$
which evaluates to $8=2\sqrt{22}\cos(\angle PQR)$, hence $\cos(\angle PQR)=\sqrt{8/11}$.  Using the identity $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, we see $\lvert\sin(\angle PQR)\rvert = \sqrt{3/11}$.  Thus, the angle of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}\lVert PQ\rVert \lVert QR\rVert\lvert\sin(\angle PQR)\rvert=\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: I dont understand why you put$2\sqrt(22)cos(PQR) = 8$ why 8?

Comment: $P-Q=(1,-1,2,-1,1)$, $R-Q=(2,-1,1,-1,2)$, and $(P-Q)\cdot (R-Q)=1\cdot 2+(-1)\cdot(-1)+2\cdot 1+(-1)\cdot(-1)+1\cdot 2=8$.  When I say "evaluates to" I mean the equation becomes that once you calculate everything you can calculate.

Comment: Great! Thank you